# Angularjs 1.5x: How to call a function only once in a template and reuse the result in multiple places

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a count of questions left in each section and that count is displayed to the user unless there are zero left in which case I display a check mark.

```
<p class="list-group-item-heading">{{section.title}}
    <i ng-show="questionsLeft(section)==0" class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span ng-show="questionsLeft(section)>0" class="label">                
            {{questionsLeft(section)}}</span>
</p>
```

The function questionsLeft() is called 3 times - how can it be called once and its result reused? I have tried both `ng-init` and the {{x = questionsLeft(section); ""}}  trick both of which initialize the variable but it does not update when the value changes.

Comment: You can create a `filter` - it will be updated with the value

Comment: i think you can write this template inside your controller itself and mention this template when and where to be apeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a variable inside `section` component controller.
2. Put this variable instead of the function inside you template.
3. Update variable value each time the number of questions is changed with `questionsLeft` function. You can do it inside $onChanges hook, for instance.

P.S. it will be easier to say if you provide the controller code